# Is it possible remove duplicates from a JSON file?

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file that I populate with data from scraping a website. More times than often it will have duplicate data, for example I provided a snippet of what the JSON file looks like. Is it possible to remove duplicates and keep the first occurrence?
Updated the most with my full code. If that makes a difference.

```
# grabs all the trending quotes for that day
def getTrendingQuotes(browser):
    # wait until trending links appear, not really needed only for example
    all_trendingQuotes = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
        lambda d: d.find_elements_by_css_selector('#trendingQuotes a')
    )
    return [link.get_attribute('href') for link in all_trendingQuotes]


def getStockDetails(url, browser):

    print(url)
    browser.get(url)

    quote_wrapper = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('div.quote-wrapper')
    quote_name = quote_wrapper.find_element_by_class_name(
        "quote-name").find_element_by_tag_name('h2').text
    quote_price = quote_wrapper.find_element_by_class_name("quote-price").text
    quote_volume = quote_wrapper.find_element_by_class_name(
        "quote-volume").text

    print("\n")
    print("Quote Name: " + quote_name)
    print("Quote Price: " + quote_price)
    print("Quote Volume: " + quote_volume)
    print("\n")

    convertToJson(quote_name, quote_price, quote_volume, url)


quotesArr = []

# Convert to a JSON  file


def convertToJson(quote_name, quote_price, quote_volume, url):
    quoteObject = {
        "url": url,
        "Name": quote_name,
        "Price": quote_price,
        "Volume": quote_volume
    }
    quotesArr.append(quoteObject)


def trendingBot(url, browser):
    browser.get(url)
    trending = getTrendingQuotes(browser)
    for trend in trending:
        getStockDetails(trend, browser)
    # requests finished, write json to file
    with open('trendingQuoteData.json', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(quotesArr, outfile)


def Main():
    scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    # applicable to windows os only
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')

    url = 'https://www.tmxmoney.com/en/index.html'
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(
         chrome_options=chrome_options)
    # browser = webdriver.Chrome(
    #   r"C:\Users\austi\OneDrive\Desktop\chromeDriver\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
    browser.get(url)

    os.system('cls')
    print("[+] Success! Bot Starting!")
    scheduler.add_job(trendingBot, 'interval', hours=1,
                      next_run_time=datetime.now(), args=[url, browser])
    scheduler.start()
    #trendingBot(url, browser)
    browser.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main()
```

---

```
[
  {
    "url": "https://web.tmxmoney.com/quote.php?qm_symbol=ACB&locale=EN",
    "Volume": "Volume:\n12,915,903",
    "Price": "$ 7.67",
    "Name": "Aurora Cannabis Inc."
  },

  {
    "url": "https://web.tmxmoney.com/quote.php?qm_symbol=HNL&locale=EN",
    "Volume": "Volume:\n548,038",
    "Price": "$ 1.60",
    "Name": "Horizon North Logistics Inc."
  },
  {
    "url": "https://web.tmxmoney.com/quote.php?qm_symbol=ACB&locale=EN",
    "Volume": "Volume:\n12,915,903",
    "Price": "$ 7.67",
    "Name": "Aurora Cannabis Inc."
  }
]
```

Comment: Yes you can easily iterate over all elements with elimination of duplicates, most efficient way is to store occurred _url_s in `set`.

Comment: What exactly qualifies as a duplicate? Must all fields be identical? Or just one or two? Also, this question is not really about JSON because what you have there is a regular Python list of regular Python dictionaries.

Comment: @Thomas If the name or the url, more so the  urls, is the same in another entry that would qualify as a duplicate.

Comment: @vishes_shell do I use set inside my converToJson() then check if they're duplicates?

Comment: @pennyBoy yes, have a global variable or pass it to `converToJson`. And check on existence, if element already occurred, then you pass, if it's first time you see then add element to set and into your array.

Comment: @Thomas so what would be the most feasible way to go about doing this problem. I appreciate if you could help.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider all entities of a dictionary as duplicate then you can go ahead with this solution:

```
# Initializing `file` variable with your list
names = []
idx = []
new_file = []
for i in range(len(file)):
    if file[i]['Name'] not in names:
        names.append(file[i]['Name'])
        idx.append(i)
        new_file.append(file[i])
print(names)
print(idx)
new_file

['Aurora Cannabis Inc.', 'Horizon North Logistics Inc.']
[0, 1]
[{'Name': 'Aurora Cannabis Inc.',
  'Price': '$ 7.67',
  'Volume': 'Volume:\n12,915,903',
  'url': 'https://web.tmxmoney.com/quote.php?qm_symbol=ACB&locale=EN'},
 {'Name': 'Horizon North Logistics Inc.',
  'Price': '$ 1.60',
  'Volume': 'Volume:\n548,038',
  'url': 'https://web.tmxmoney.com/quote.php?qm_symbol=HNL&locale=EN'}]
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to a pythonic way of doing this...

```
arr = [
  {
    "url": "https://web.tmxmoney.com/quote.php?qm_symbol=ACB&locale=EN",
    "Volume": "Volume:\n12,915,903",
    "Price": "$ 7.67",
    "Name": "Aurora Cannabis Inc."
  },

  {
    "url": "https://web.tmxmoney.com/quote.php?qm_symbol=HNL&locale=EN",
    "Volume": "Volume:\n548,038",
    "Price": "$ 1.60",
    "Name": "Horizon North Logistics Inc."
  },
  {
    "url": "https://web.tmxmoney.com/quote.php?qm_symbol=ACB&locale=EN",
    "Volume": "Volume:\n12,915,903",
    "Price": "$ 7.67",
    "Name": "Aurora Cannabis Inc."
  }
]

def drop_duplicates(arr):
    """ Appends the item to the returned array only if not
        already present in our dummy array that serves as reference.
    """
    selected  = []
    urls = []
    for item in arr:
        if item['url'] not in urls:
            selected.append(item)
            urls.append(item['url'])
    return selected

print( drop_duplicates(arr) )
```

Comment: This checks for reference equality only, so it won't work except if you have the exact same dictionary object multiple times in the list. Which you don't, if you parsed it from JSON.

Comment: @Thomas This is not true. Reference equality is made using the operator `is`, not `in`. So I'm checking equality. You can create two identical dictionnaries in two different variables (different identity, you can check the id()), and if you check equality (meaning `==`), it'll be True. --- That being said, I updated my answer because OP was not clear enough is his question and added details in comments. :)

Comment: @IMCoins sorry for not being clear in my question. I updated the post with my full code as well. Is it possible for me to just use your function and call it like this quotesArr.append(drop_duplicates(quoteObject))?

Comment: @pennyBoy This function takes your final list and keeps the first occurrence of an element, based on its url. If you want to check if the element exists before adding it to your list, it's just a different operation / problem you want to face. :)

Comment: @IMCoins  think I understand.

Comment: @pennyBoy When you need to drop the duplicates, do `new_arr = drop_duplicates(quotesArr)`

Comment: @IMCoins it stills keeps the duplicates :(  `quotesArr.append(quoteObject)  
    newQuotesarr = drop_duplicates(quotesArr)` Thats what I implemented in my code, then i called `json.dump(newQuotesarr, outfile)`

Comment: @pennyBoy I don't understand. I am testing it from my side with an array of dict, with an array of dict that I convert to string, that i re-convert to an array of dict, with a json_string that I load as an array of dict, and it works everytime. The duplicate from my side are dropped. I also use the dataset you provide, and it does work. You must be doing something wrong, OR -- let's assume that's possible : Thomas is right somewhere and I don't know where I am wrong.

Comment: @IMCoins Can you show me how you set up based on my full code above?